# Finding the worpress installation logwatch is referring to

Tags: ubuntu, wordpress

Today, I got

```
 A total of 2 possible successful probes were detected (the following URLs
 contain strings that match one or more of a listing of strings that
 indicate a possible exploit):

    /wp-content/plugins/wptf-image-gallery/lib-mbox/ajax_load.php?url=../../../../wp-config.php HTTP Response 301 
    /wp-content/themes/mTheme-Unus/css/css.php?files=../../../../wp-config.php HTTP Response 301
```

from Logwatch.

I did `find / -name wptf-image-gallery -type d` on my server to remove it but there was no result.

What should I do now? How do I find the affected wordpress installation?

Answer (score 0):

The `HTTP Response 301` indicates HTTP redirection, not an actual successful response. There's more possible reasons for that than the file actually existing. Because Logwatch uses the logs (not the file system), you should `grep` through the logs to find the correct virtual host.

After that you can find if there's these plugins/themes installed and whether the versions are vulnerable. Or if there's even a WordPress.